# How to prevent displaying the echo command line itself on output of text using command echo?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hopefully this is a simple question...

I'm using a batch file to move some files around that is for various, unfortunate, reasons is somewhat complicated. To run properly it is necessary to right-click and "Run as Administrator".

To remind the unwashed masses and me to do that step I want the first line to Echo "This file must be ran by right-clicking and choosing "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR".

Then a Pause.

What I get is the complete command displayed when all I want is the instructional text. See below.

```
C:\Users\TEST>echo This file must be ran by right-clicking and choosing "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR"
This file must be ran by right-clicking and choosing "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR"
```

Either I am asking Google the wrong question\wording or I am the first person in history to not be able to figure this out on my own. Is this possible or am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 1):

Put an `@` at the beginning of the echo:

```
@echo This file must be ...
```

or make the first line of your batch file:

```
@echo off
```

to suppress the command-line echo of each command.

Comment: Thanks Jim. The @ was just what I needed. I was hoping that it would be something simple.